Where and how does the $5$ digit Come from? Integral with Euler $e$ constant
I am currently practicing Integrals and Primitive Functions. I solved many of them. However, ran into one very strange.
$f(x)=x+e^{-0,2x} -e^{-x}$
My unsuccessful attempt:
$F(x)=\frac{x^2}{2} + e^{-x}$
$\int e^{-0.2x} dx = \frac{1}{a}e^{ax}$
$\int -\frac{1}{0.2}e^{-0.2x}dx$
The solution according to my book:
$$F(x)=\frac{x^2}{2} -5e^{-0.2x} + e^{-x}$$
I found some steps here:
https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Calculus/563436
But, I am confused to fully understand. Can someone kindly explain what is happening and why?

Did you miss that $1/0.2=5$?

@Karl, care to explain? How exactly?

Well, $0.2=2/10=1/5.$ Consider reviewing how to multiply and divide fractions and decimals.
